# control in same or next row style

Tags: android, css, html, responsive-design

I want a label and a control to behave as follows:

- if the the width of the screen in less than X the label and the control should be in different rows and the control should expand to take the full width.
- if the width is higher (or equal) than X, the label and the control should be in the same row and the control should be aligned right. Also, the text and the control should be vertically aligned center:

[image: vertically aligned center description]

I have this code ([test the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yuw8k/)):

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="dispInlineLabel" >
        <label for="rb_geschlecht-2a">Geschlecht</label>
    </div>
    <div class="dispInline">
        <fieldset  data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">                     
            <input type="radio" name="rb_geschlecht" id="rb_geschlecht-2a" value="0">
            <label for="rb_geschlecht-2a">weiblich</label>
            <input type="radio" name="rb_geschlecht" id="rb_geschlecht-2b" value="1">
            <label for="rb_geschlecht-2b">männlich</label>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div class="clearFloats"></div>

    <div class="dispInlineLabel" >
        <label for="ti_gebdat">Geburtsdatum</label>
    </div>
    <div class="dispInline">       
        <input name="ti_gebdat" id="ti_gebdat" style="text-align: right" type="date"  data-theme="d">
    </div>
    <div class="clearFloats"></div>                                     
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.dispInline, .dispInlineLabel{
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom-width:0;
}
.dispInlineLabel{
    min-width: 120px;
}
.dispInline{
    float:right;
}
.clearFloats{
    clear:both;
}
```

Here, the control and label are in different or same row as expected.
My problems are:

- When the control is in a different row, it doesn't expand to full width.
- Control and label are not "vertically aligned center" when on the same row

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use media query like this:

```
@media all and (max-width: 500px){
  .dispInline{
      width:100%;
    }
}
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/yuw8k/1/)

[*more info*](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)

## update:

for vertically align you need to set all rows in a same height then set line height to your labels as the height:

**CSS**

```
.dispInlineLabel{
    min-width: 120px;
    height:55px;
}
.dispInlineLabel label{
    line-height:55px;
}
.dispInline{
    float:right;
    height:55px;
}
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yuw8k/2/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that solves a part of it. Any idea on how to vertically align the control and the label?